# How can I parse only one node at a time?

Tags: .net, xml, parsing

I just want to load only one node at a time into memory instead of loading the entire XML document. Please help me to find this. I have xml document like this..`<Report><Data><Row>..</Row><Row>..</Row><Row>..</Row>`

Here i get millions of rows like this and hence i need to load only one row at a time into memory. Is there any .Net class available? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class which

> Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data.

Comment: hi jeff..thanks... i m new to xml. can you please tel me how to load only one Node using xmlreader class?

Comment: Does the code sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(VS.95).aspx help?

Answer (score 0):

Well I love LINQ to XML, I really hate parsing XML, but LINQ makes it easier. The problem is large documents would eat memory since the whole XML will be loaded in memory.

This [post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2007/12/11/linq-to-xml-over-large-documents.aspx) shows how you can use LINQ to XML and the XMLReader, so you have the ease of use of LINQ to SQL but the memory efficiency of XMLReader.